# vlc onlistnener needed to know the end of the video

Tags: vlc

Im using VLC to play video but I need to know when the video ends. so basically I need a `onlistener`. Can someone give me a simple code for `onlistener` for VLC. Here is the code I'm using to play VLC :

```
     int vlcRequestCode = 42;  Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Download/hero.mp4");
vlcIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.videolan.vlc", "org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity"));
vlcIntent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "video/*");
vlcIntent.putExtra("title", " Concert Collection");
vlcIntent.putExtra("from_start", true);
vlcIntent.putExtra("position", 90000l);
vlcIntent.putExtra("position", 90000l);
startActivityForResult(vlcIntent, vlcRequestCode);
```

Comment: `org.videolan.vlc.player.result` as detailed here https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/

Comment: Could you give an example just like they have onlistnerer for textview? becasue I'm not sure were to start with that link?

Comment: Nope! I don't use android or java. Perhaps this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426840/vlc-intent-always-returns-result-code-0-result-canceled